# Why process is using more than 100% of CPU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, top, cpu-usage, htop

I need to know why those processes are using so many CPUs. Are there any commands or tools to check?

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                
 3562 ypa       20   0 3289448 565568 221932 S  122.3   7.0  34:19.52 Web Content                                                                                                                            
 3355 ypa       20   0 3754528 562308 216728 S  97.0   7.0  51:18.91 firefox
```

Answer (score 2):

Unix/Linux shows a process and overall CPU usage differently than Windows.

In Windows 100% = all CPU cores, including virtual ones.

In Linux/Unix 100% = a single CPU core.

Actually the way Linux/Unix shows it, it's a lot more natural/logical, because imagine you have an eight-core CPU with hyperthreading/SMT. In Windows a process which occupies one CPU core will show 6% CPU use which is kinda hard to grasp. When you have a 64-thread CPU, it'll be even less, just 1 or 2% (not sure how rounding works).